# How to flatten subarrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, flatten

I have the following structure

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['l', 'm', 'n']]]
```

and I want to obtain the following:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['l', 'm', 'n']]
```

I've tried the following:

```
a.flatten => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n']

a.flatten(1) => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['l', 'm', 'n']]
```

the solution I found, for now, is to change the initial structure to this format:

```
b = [[['a', 'b', 'c']], [['d', 'e', 'f']], [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['l', 'm', 'n']]]
```

and then call

```
b.flatten(1) => [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['l', 'm', 'n']]
```

but I could do this only because I was able to change how `a` was built. My question remains: how to obtain my desired result starting from `a`?

Comment: If you know that you need/have triples (arrays of size 3), I'd go with a solution that does not answer your question :) and `flatten` then slice.

Comment: No, the number of elements inside each array is not fixed, and also the number of arrays and subarrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a.each_with_object([]) do |e, memo|
  e == e.flatten ? memo << e : e.each { |e| memo << e }
end
#⇒ [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i'], ['l', 'm', 'n']]
```

Comment: Looking forward for something more elegant but your solution is working nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Other solution:

```
a.flat_map { |e| e[0].is_a?(Array) ? e : [e] }
#=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"], ["l", "m", "n"]]
```

Comment: `a.flat_map { |e| e.flatten == e ? [e] : e }` also works

Comment: `Array#flat?` would be quite handy here.

Comment: @coorasse, it is more efficient to check just first element instead of transform all array and then check

Comment: @Stefan, can you give a link on this method docs? I could not find it.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't exist. I wanted to say that such a method would be useful.